# XCode 4.4.1 - What is new

Tags: xcode, macos, updates

I just updated my Xcode from 4.4 to 4.4.1, but I can't seem to find what changes they have made to Xcode. Could anyone please enlighten me? I can only find the changes for 4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new in xcode 4.4;

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011649-SW1

I think 4.4.1 is just a small fix of a very small issue, nothing big!